# How to convert ISO 8601 utc time to datetime format in SQL server 2016

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to import some data from a flat file into SQL SERVER 2016. In the flat file, there is a date data in ISO 8061 UTC format

```
eg: 2017-10-08T00:00:00.0000000Z
```

While creating the table in sql server, I created the column as datetime. But now when I try to do a select on this particular column it is throwing error as:

```
Expected data type: DATETIME NOT NULL, Offending value: 2017-10-08T00:00:00.0000000Z  (Column Conversion Error), Error: Conversion failed when converting the NVARCHAR value '2017-10-08T00:00:00.0000000Z' to data type DATETIME.
```

Is there anyway to resolve this. I tried the below statement in SQL server:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, DateColumnISO, 127) FROM myTable;
```

This again threw the same error.

Thanks,
Arjun

Comment: should have not been `2017-10-08T00:00:00.000Z` instead of `2017-10-08T00:00:00.0000000Z`?

Answer (score 4):

You have too much precision to `convert` to a `datetime`.  Either strip out everything past milliseconds or `convert` to a `datetime2`:

```
select convert(datetime, '2017-10-08T00:00:00.000Z'    ,127) as ConvertedToDateTime
      ,convert(datetime2,'2017-10-08T00:00:00.0000000Z',127) as ConvertedToDateTime2
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
|   ConvertedToDateTime   |     ConvertedToDateTime2     |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| 2017-10-08 00:00:00.000 | 2017-10-08 00:00:00.0000000  |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: I get proper data when trying the above query in SQL. However when I substitute teh actual date data with the column name, it throws the below error:

     Column ordinal: 0, Expected data type: DATETIME NOT NULL, Offending value: 2017-10-08T00:00:00.0000000Z  (Column Conversion Error), Error: Conversion failed when converting the NVARCHAR value '2017-10-08T00:00:00.0000000Z' to data type DATETIME.

Comment: Yes, because you are trying to convert a value with a very high precision to `datetime`.  You need to change your column to a `datetime2` value.